# AWS SAM - Using Cognito for access controls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

In the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis.html) for "Controlling Access to API Gateway APIs" it says:

> The mechanism that you choose to control access to your API Gateway APIs depends on a few factors. For example, if you have a greenfield project that doesn't have either authorization or access control set up yet, then Amazon Cognito user pools might be your best option. This is because when you set up user pools, you also set up both authentication and access control automatically.

I've set up authentication using `AWS::Serverless::Api` in AWS SAM:

```
 MyApi:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn:<MY_RESOURCE_ARN>
```

I'm not clear on what is meant by:

> you also set up both authentication **and access control automatically**

I have a GET endpoint which should only be accessible depending on the users identity. Currently, users must be logged in to be able query the endpoint, but how does Cognito allow authorization to be configured in addition to authentication?

I would like to be able to configure it so some users are allowed to call:

`/api/group_profile/a`
but not:
`/api/group_profile/b`

I think I understand how this can be done with a lambda authorizer, but the documentation seems to suggest that if you don't already have authentication setup, you can use Cognito for this purpose?

---

Within the .NET Core Lambda function I can look at the ClaimsPrincipal on `HttpContext.User` and check the `cognito:groups`. Is this the recommended approach?

I don't see how this will work with caching enabled on the API Gateway and will pose challenges for running the API locally.